# Microsoft Edge - C# Error - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, microsoft-edge

Hi its facing issue with datetime formatting in my MVC Controller Get method.
Its working fine when request send from Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer,
But it **throws an exception while request comes from Microsoft Edge browser** :(

> Exception :  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Sample Code is here -

```
public JsonResult GetFYDetailsForDate(string date)
{
    //input date = "6/13/2018"
    DateTimeStyles dateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal;
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

    var culturedDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

    var culturedDate = DateTime.Parse(date, culture, dateTimeStyles);

}
```

Imput Date is "6/13/2018" and Parsed Date output is "6/13/2018 12:00:00 AM" if request comes from Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

> ** To resolve this we can extract date, month and year from date string, but I don't want to do that. Just want to know what is wrong with
>   request comes from Microsoft Edge browser.

Code screenshot -
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the input comming from Edge is the expected? Is it not like `6 13 2018`?

Comment: When you debug with a breakpoint at this point of code what is the date string value?

Comment: @Nekeniehl, yes the input "6/13/2018" is commented in code is copied from request coming from Edge.

Comment: Try to do `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`; I am not at the computer and cannot do it myself

Comment: Thanks Neken, I have tried it but its not working. I have added screenshot of code so you can see input date string there.

Comment: Look for any extra characters that might be coming in with the payload. For instance, when your breakpoint is hit, in the Immediate Window, compare `date.Length` to what you think it should be (in the example case of `"6/20/2018"`, I would expect it to be `9`). If it's greater, you may need to used `date.Trim()` or some other cleanup on the string before parsing.

Comment: Have you tried DateTime.ParseExact(date, “M/dd/yyyy”,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: On the point of extra characters, while in debug mode on a value that is failing, expand the string to view the character array.  Maybe somehow you have some hidden character or unicode value hiding in the string.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the length of string shows 14 instead of 9. Good catch, Thanks for help :)

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks :)

Comment: Wasted some hours on this ... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with input date string when it comes from Microsoft Edge browser. Date string contains characters **(Char)8206** that's why C# unable to parse the date and throws an error. Visible length of string is 9, but actual length of string is 14. So I have removed those hidden characters from string and its working perfectly fine now.

Below code snippet I have used to sanitize string, please suggest any better and efficient way to do this.

Thanks you.

```
string sanitizedDateString = new String(inputDate.ToCharArray().Where(x => x != (Char)8206).ToArray());
```

Comment: `8206` (hex `200E`) is a [left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) character.  You can replace it with `inputDate.Replace("\u200E","")` instead of all the above.  However, I would recommend you look into why you are getting this from the browser side in the first place. There are probably some culture/local issues.